# Show that $f=g$, if $f(z)=g(z)$ for $z\in dA$ with $A$ bounded region

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $A$ be a bounded region, $f$, $g$ continuous functions of $\bar{A}$ in the complex. Suppose that these functions are holomorphic in the region and agree on the border. Prove you are the same.

I think this problem is solved by the maximum modulus principle, where we know that:
$$M=sup_{z\in dA}|f(z)|=sup_{z\in dA}|g(z)|$$
consequently:
$$f(z)\le M$$ and $$g(z)\le M$$
However, I do not know how to use these observations, I think without ideas, or how I can use that the region is bounded?

Comment: $dA$ is the border of $A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: The function $h(z) := f(z) - g(z)$ is holomorphic in $A$ and continuous on $\overline{A}$. What is its value on the boundary, and how does the maximum modulus principle give the result now?

Comment: Ohhh, Okey, thanks, its value on the boundary is zero, and by maximum modulus principle:

Comment: $|f(z)-g(z)|\le 0$